# Как программно эмулировать нажатие Ctrl+Alt+Del из кода на C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Кто-нибудь знает как можно эмулировать нажатие Ctrl+Alt+Del из C# кода?

Знаю, что это "невозможно и так задумано в майкрософт.." + специальное аппаратное прерывание и что-то там еще сложного, но..

Есть множество программ типа Radmin, TeamViewer и прочие которые без проблем справляются с этой задачей во всех версиях windows. Опять же экранная клавиатура может эмулировать это сочетание.. Соответственно задача должна быть решаема, но как к ней подступиться не могу понять((

Может кто уже сталкивался с подобным и успешно решил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная операция называется Secure Attention Sequence ([SAS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd979761(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Для вызова можно воспользоваться WinAPI:

```
VOID WINAPI SendSAS(
  _In_ BOOL AsUser
);
```

Подробнее на эту тему [тут](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2009/03/30/sending-ctrl-alt-del-simulate-sas-in-windows-vista/)

Comment: Sas.dll is not available natively. You must download the Windows 7 version of the Microsoft Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) to use this function... Во всем распространенном софте все работает из коробки. Без всяких заморочек и прочего.. То есть должно быть более универсальное решение проблемы..

Answer (score 1):

Программный запуск Ctrl+Alt+Del из службы C#:

```
[DllImport("sas.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern void SendSAS(bool fUser);

SendSAS(false);
```

Так же в редакторе объектов груповой политики включить:

Конфигурация компьютера > Административные шаблоны > Компоненты Windows > Параметры входа Windows > Разрешить или запретить программам использование специального сочетания клавиш - Включить, в качестве программ задать "службы"

Тестировалось на Win7 - работает.